# Flow refinement with `$Keys` to union type and type casting

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

[Flow has a utility type `$Keys`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys) that let's you create union types from Objects:

```js
// @flow
const countries = {
  US: "United States",
  IT: "Italy",
  FR: "France"
};

type Country = $Keys<typeof countries>;
// Equivalent to:
// type Country = 'US' | 'IT' | 'FR'
```

However, if I am getting a value that I am not sure is a valid `Country` or not, I'd think I'd be able to refine the type via a [type casting expression](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/#toc-type-cast-expression-syntax) and then continue on with the rest of the logic. But I can't get that to work.

Take this [example code](https://flow.org/try/#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):

```js
// @flow

const countries = {
  US: "United States",
  IT: "Italy",
  FR: "France"
};

type Country = $Keys<typeof countries>;

function someCountry(): Country | string {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'US' : 'other';
}

function doThingWithCountry(val: Country) {
  // ...
}

let country = someCountry();
if (country in countries) {
    // The following typecast line reports this error:
    // Cannot cast `country` to `Country` because an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing in object literal [1]. [prop-missing]
    country = (country: Country);

    doThingWithCountry(country);
}
```

The error it returns is

> Cannot cast `country` to `Country` because an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing in object literal [1]. [prop-missing]

Trying other conditionals like `if (countries[country])` or `if (countries.hasOwnProperty(country))` also give the same error.

Is there something I'm missing with how [refinements](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) are supposed to work?

Note that a simpler refinement conditional like `if (country === 'US')` [does work as you'd expect](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AYVgK4B2KATmqALygDkAqgMo2gA+tAkgCrNs0BiAJRoBuZJGIBjFAEtYRUAGdYAWyz5iZNAAoAlAC48hEuVaKy0ogHNQAb0QBIUlhQFS8gLIBDFAAsAdKSeRAAmKrqgAHygAAx+AKygAPy0jMwGNLC+WKQiiAC+YpIycqChnD4WlgDq0r7qxtoAbp7QBvWaOraIoKAgoH4D+cjQzqASRppUiipqE+S6otKQoFrjGiaUmylMrGxrDVRbNFw8e3MUm9T8Qp12PT195dIKoPCwpADWL54vWAAe2CkWGC3Xu+0m1FW5za5x0olBPTKFSsNTq5yh6zQcPyQA):

```js
// @flow

type Country = 'US' | 'IT' | 'FR';

function someCountry(): Country | string {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'US' : 'other';
}

function doThingWithCountry(val: Country) {
  // ...
}

let country = someCountry();
if (country === 'US' || country === 'IT' || country === 'FR') {
    // This works as expected
    country = (country: Country);

    doThingWithCountry(country);
}
```

Comment: Looks like `in` and `hasOwnProperty` do not count as a refinements in Flow

Comment: Wonder if flow team is working on including those as a refinement. Otherwise should raise an issue on github.